# It sounds like that there is a "v" in "generally", What I saw at her mouth matches what I heard. Why is that?

Tags: pronunciation

The speaker is lecturing (https://youtu.be/vzsQkjX4fD8)

> whether you are an English Learner an
>   actor or someone *generally* interested in
>   linguistics learning the IPA the
>   international phonetic alphabet is going
>   to greatly benefit you.

It sounds like that there is a "v" in "generally", What I saw at her mouth matches what I heard.

The image shown below is a screenshot at the time stamp just before she pronounce "v", about 0:04.03. *Note:* 03 is my estimate, since youtube does not show milliseconds (may youtube supports but I don't know)

[image]

Comment: Where (at what point in the word) did you hear the V? I just heard very clear, slightly robotic, pronunciation of her words for the benefit of her audience.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie The image I posted is a screenshot at the time stamp just before she pronounce "v", about 0:04.03. *Note:* 03 is my estimate, since youtube does not show milliseconds (may youtube supports but I don't know)

Comment: I seriously doubt you can “see” this pronunciation. In any case, the image of her lips is hardly important if we don’t hear the sound. I think we are off topic.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Did you actually listen the time stamp where I pointed out?

Comment: Listening over again I do get a hint of what I think of as a “British lisp” which in this case is “generally” pronounced a bit like “genwerllay”. I think this is a feature of a “posh” British accent but I’m no expert by any means and we need a British English speaker to get involved. *(I still can’t “see” the lisp and I was trying to hear a V when it turned out to be a soft W! Anyway, I’m glad we got somewhere in the end.)*

Comment: A bit of research tells me this may be the error/feature described in Merriam-Webster as: *rhotacism*
1 : a defective pronunciation of r
especially : substitution of some other sound for that of r

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thank you so much. First of all, did you actually catch the "v"? Secondly, are “British lisp” and "rhotacism" the same thing? I guess not, just for sure.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie says that 'British lisp' is just his/her name for rhotacism. Actually it is neither a lisp nor particularly British. It is sometimes used to parody British   upper-class accents, but in fact it's a speech defect. The speaker in the video doesn't have it markedly, but she does pronounce the 'r' in 'generally' like a 'w' (definitely not a 'v').

Comment: @KateBunting. Is that what I said? Here’s me thinking I was denying expertise and inviting a British English speaker to clarify the whole thing for us, knowing full well that Mr Google (a number of hastily considered sources) might be deceiving me. Thank you, for doing that anyway.

Comment: @OrbitalAussie To clarify, rhotacism is the inability to pronounce the letter 'r' (as distinct from a non-rhotic dialect, whose speakers don't pronounce some 'r' sounds that others do). See https://blog.cognifit.com/rhotacism/ .

Comment: @KateBunting. The clarification unconsciously compounds the rudeness by telling me how to suck eggs  - I already gave *you* the definition (*and* I’m a non-rhotic Australian too!).  I’ll put all this down to inattention instead and do a better job of correcting my earlier comments myself...

Comment: The idea though that rhotacism is a feature of posh British accents (Received Pronunciation - RP) is a MYTH. Relevantly at least, rhotacism involves a substitution of a complicated sound some people think of as a “w” in the place where other speakers pronounce an “r”. RP doesn’t do that. The reason this myth arose, and was perpetuated by comedians, is probably because RP does involve some marked blurring of vowels and clipping of pronunciation. This might sound like a defect in speech or lisping to some people, but its just an accent: http://www.yorku.ca/earmstro/speech/dialects/rp/index.html

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Does MYTH refer to a normal myth, something like a traditional story? or a abbreviation stands for something else?

Comment: *Definition of myth* (Merriam-Webster)
2a : a popular belief or tradition that has grown up around something...
b : an unfounded or false notion
//the myth of racial superiority

Comment: @OrbitalAussie Thank you! Does MYTH here indicate that "rhotacism is a feature ..." is a false notion?

Comment: @OrbitalAussie I really wasn't intending to be rude. You had asked for input from a British English speaker, and I was trying to clarify things for the OP, who thought your term 'British lisp' and rhoticism were different. The explanation wasn't directed at you.

Answer (score 1):

The sounds she is making in the word "generally" are, as I interpret them, /'dʒɛnrwəli:/. The sound you are asking about you I have notated as /rw/, by which I mean a single sound that seems like a blend of /r/ and /w/.

To quote Wikipedia > "Cockney" in the (rather long) "Typical features" section: "Cockney has been occasionally described as replacing /ɹ/ with /w/. For example, thwee (or fwee) instead of three, fwasty instead of frosty. Peter Wright, a Survey of English Dialects fieldworker, concluded that this was not a universal feature of Cockneys but that it was more common to hear this in the London area than elsewhere in Britain.[83] This description may also be a result of mishearing the labiodental R as /w/, when it is still a distinct phoneme in Cockney."

Although most of my schoolfriends had more or less Cockney accents, I cannot quite describe this /rw/ sound or even reproduce it myself. Perhaps it is simply a /w/ on the lips and a simultaneous /r/ on the tongue.